# I have an issue related to scraping date from a website using python and Beautifulsoup like there it is the splitting issue where `.split('.', "")

Tags: python, datetime, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, strptime

I have an issue related to scraping date from a website using python and Beautifulsoup like there I am facing the splitting issue where `.split('.', "")` is not working on scraping only date from this p tag `<p class="text-xs">Oct 24, 2017 • 4 min read</p>` Actually I don't want this dot and 4 min read from this p tag

```
Published_Date = soup.select_one('p[class="text-xs"]').get('datetime')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The bold big dot `•` is different that `.` dot you are using in split() method.
2. So replace the bold big dot with a symbol and split that symbol and take the first value using list slicing

**Example:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html ='''
<p class="text-xs">Oct 24, 2017 • 4 min read</p>

'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

date = soup.select_one('p.text-xs').get_text(strip=True)
print(date.replace('•','|').split('|')[0])
```

**Output:**

```
Oct 24, 2017
```